# SpriteBatch memory leak

Tags: xna, c#

I have a strange problem with XNA 4. I'm constructing a `SpriteBatch` using `this.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch( GraphicsDevice );`.
This leads to a memory leak up to 600 MB memory consumption.

This problem didn't exist two days ago.

I have a static class called `Resources`:

```
public static GraphicsDeviceManager gdm;
```

This gets set in the `Game`-constructor

```
public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game {
    public Game() {
        Resources.gdm = new GraphicsDeviceManager( this );
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
}
```

In the `Initialize`-Method I'm creating a SpriteBatch in the `Resources`

```
protected override void Initialize() {
    base.Initialize();
    Resources.Game = this;
    Resources.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch( GraphicsDevice );
}
```

At the point `Resources.spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch( GraphicsDevice );` it allocates up to 600 MB memory.

Why is XNA allocating so much after I created a `SpriteBatch`? How can I fix it? (It worked two days ago and I didn't change anything that could cause this problem.)

Comment: Nothing in the code you provided causes the memory leak. You need to post more code. Also, I doubt that anything like creating a new SpriteBatch object (except maybe if you are doing it every frame) would cause such a massive memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fault of `SpriteBatch`.  It's much more likely to be the fault of your `Resources` object.  By the way, keeping track of resources is the job of the `Game` class.  I would be skeptical that you have good reason to also assign a `GraphicsDevice` into your custom object.  Afterall, `Game` already has one, and it ought to be a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Do you call `Game.Initialize()` in your `Resources` object?  I once had similar symptoms because I called `base.Initialize();` in my game's `LoadContent` method.  (Infinite allocations until stack overflow.)  You might try stepping into your code from `Main` by simply hitting F11.  See if the execution does anything that it shouldn't be doing, and see if it is doing it over and over and over.